# Can I add one folder from hard disk to my classpath for all projects in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I have one folder named `library` where I have put all my JAR files.
Now every time I create a new project, I have to copy all my JAR files in the lib folder to the WEB-INF folder.

Is there any way that I can add a folder permanently to all projects in Eclipse so that I don't need to put all the JAR files again and again in new projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of doing or approaching this.

1. Use a java endorsed library (if the jars correspond to an [endorsable standard](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/standards/)) (can be done outside eclipse). Be aware that this affects the Bootstrap Class loader (and so will the creation of an eclipse user *system* library).
2. Use a jars manually to your JRE library (inside eclipse). Window => Preferences = Java => Installed JRE, select one => add... => Add external jar.  This will add the selected jar even to existing projects referring to this JRE.  If you work with multiple JREs, you can have one "tweaked one" and a "standard one" for each Java version.
3. Define a user library (Window => Preferences => Java => Build Path => User libraries)  This is commonly used to group jars.  Still you will need to manually add the library to each project.  Benefit: the jar are grouped (eg jdbc drivers, SWT version, etc...).
4. Define a library project (containing only jars and libraries) and manually add the library project to all projects in which you need these references.

Only the first 2 solutions are fully automated.  Yet if you want to be able to opt out on a per-project basis, I'd recommend solution 3 (preferably) or 4.  With solution 2, you can still opt out by using a standard JRE for untainted projects.

Now answering a question with another question.  What is your use case when you need to add one or more jars to *all* projects ?

Comment: Actually i am just experimenting with codes ,so daily i ahve to make 3-4 projects and its annoying to add jars every time

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on the project name in the Navigator.
- Select `Java Build Path`
- Select `Add External JARS`
- Browse to the location of your JAR files
- Select all JAR files you want to add and click OK.
- Click OK to close the Properties window.

Comment: but i have to do it for all projects each time i create new project. i want that it should be applied for all new projects not adding every time